# The top bar color when app is inactive. (Cordova)

Tags: cordova

I am developing a mobile App hybrid based on the cord, until now I'm doing well, but I can not change the color of the top bar when the application is inactive! Android 5.1 Cordova 5.3.3 I'm using the plugin (cordova_plugin-statusbar 1.0.1): https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-statusbar

[image]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NSQPI.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long time this since this question was created but I just jumped into the same issue.

cordova-plugin-statusbar is not your plugin, you need **cordova-plugin-headercolor** to update the color in multitask view -> https://github.com/tomloprod/cordova-plugin-headercolor.